# Wordpress table that contains/aids in generation of urls

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the table in the wordpress database that contains (or helps in the generation of) the URLs such as of posts images etc?

The reason why I am asking is, I have a wordpress theme installed on my server. It was previously on the `localhost`. I uploaded the theme and "whole database" from the local server to the remote server. The theme is working fine except for the reason that all the URLs are now redirect me to `localhost/qmihospital/...` while it should be `qmihospital.org/...` I thought the problem might be due to the database, so I modified every link in the database from `localhost/qmihospital` to `http://www.qmihospital.org`. Still the problem is same. Can anyone please tell me what I might have missed. Why the links are not being generated correctly?

I've been trying for the last 3 hours but I am unable to root out the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change url into database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace (option_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 
  'http://www.newsite.com')         
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace 
(guid , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace 
   (post_content , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace 
(meta_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');
```

here replace oldsite with localhost and newsite with new url and then after go to admin panel >> settings >> permalinks >> update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have had already updated the database but haven't had visited the permalinks page. I'm sorry to say but there is not update option there. I am using wordpress 3.7.

Comment: I just did that. But nothing changed :(

Comment: Do you have added any plugin for caching?

Comment: No. There was one called "Super Cache" but it was already deactivated. However I removed it now and resaved the permalinks but nothing changed.

Comment: if all urls are changed in db and you have removed cache plugin then just try in other browser, you haven't used yet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40956/discussion-between-bhumi-shah-and-kamran-ahmed)